# Python/Flask - Reference Textfile IN a Javascript File

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, ajax

This is simple if I was doing it in static html files, but as i'm working with Flask it is surprisingly difficult.

I have a html page which correctly includes a Javascript file. This java script files has an AJAX function that will read a textfile.

Does anyone know if I can reference a textfile in Javascript within a Python flask webapp?

HTML:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/my.js') }}"></script>
```

JS:

```
function alertFunc() {
  $.ajax({
      url : "/Users/me/myfile.txt", //I believe this is the issue!
      dataType: "text",
      success : function (data) {
          $("#div1").html(data);
      }
  });
```

I have put a test function in this JS file and it works so there is no issue with linking the HTML page with the JS page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add your `.txt` file to your static folder

then point to `/static/my.txt`

or add an endpoint (`@app.route('my_text.txt')`) and return it ...

its really easy... im not sure why you had the dig on flask ... I think its just as easy in flask as html and your powers in flask are much greater than simple html ...

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask,render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**static/main.js**

```
function alertFunc() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/static/my_text.txt", 
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            $("#div1").text(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**static/my_text.txt**

```
just a simple message
```

**templates/index.html**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/main.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>

<script>
    alertFunc()
</script>
```

Comment: I have already tried adding it to the static folder!, but referencing a txt file within JS file is not working in this manner: {{ url_for('static',filename='my.txt') }}

Comment: Ok so I understand how to put it in the static folder, but can you give me a clear example of how to reference the text file in JS?---------- URL: /static/my.txt ??

Comment: Thank you! I cant believe it was that simple!!